# Access Denied MySql 5.7.27

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a problem with my mysql server, that when trying to connect appears the message 'access denied', I tried to reset the password, reinstall mysql and it did not work, would anyone have any material that can help me?

S.O. = Ubuntu 8.04

Ty.

Comment: could you add some more context like, 
1. how did you install the mysql server?
2. what commands did you try to connect with ?

Comment: I tried to follow this: https://dev.to/oneearedmusic/access-denied-reset-mysql-root-user-password-2hk4 , and i reinstall all packages.